# Disable web part edit programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

in some custom web part i need to disable properties editing, on certain conditions. 
I was hoping that i do this by overriding the AllowEdit property forcing to return false, but appear to be useless.

I simply need to disable the ribbon's button "Web Part Properties" and the context menu's button "Edit Web Part".

Some hint?

Thanks

Comment: best idea is to add javascript or simple css code to hide / disable those button

Comment: i tought at this solution, but i hoped in use of AllowEdit property. thanks